# Load Balancers w/ Name-based Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, virtualhost, amazon-web-services, lamp

Are there any issues using Amazon's Elastic Load Balancer to forward requests to multiple EC2 instances that use name-based virtual hosting? In other words, is the HTTP header forwarded properly so Apache can determine which files to serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do name-based virtual hosting with ELB.